# What are the iphone's accelerometer values when it is thrown in the air (airborne)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, accelerometer

I want to do something with an app that if you throw the iphone into the air, or you are airborne with it, then some pattern changes.

I thought it was 0, but lately, I've been getting some doubts.

Or, maybe, if there isn't a fixed accelerometer value when the iphone is airborne, what is the accelerometer values when the home button is on the bottom part of the iphone (like when you normally would hold it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer) to the code that will show you Accelerometer values.

Just implement in your iPhone/iPod and throw the device in the air and you will get the X, Y and Z value.

there on you can perform the task you need,.

Answer (score 2):

Write a Logger App. Run it. Throw your phone into the air. Read logs when you catch it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My guess: The raw accelerometer values won't be 0 because you always have gravity effects in combination with rotation of the device in the air. You will rarely get a motion without spin and thus the rotation might influence even userAceleration values i.e. the acceleration delivered by core motion fusion algorithm.